# Running a python script multiple times with different variables each iteration

Tags: python

I am currently simulation light passing through an optics system with python and Zemax. I have it set up currently where I define the x and y boundaries of the "sensor" to that i can choose the size of the area I want to simulate. I get 1 rectangle.

I'd like to simulate nine rectangles, in a 3x3 Grid. I am unsure which way would be the most elegant... my first Idea was to "hardcode" the different intervals into 9 different scripts and run those through a bash script, but it seemst a bit to "unelegant".

How do I have to define xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin now so that i can run the same simulation and get those nine retangles?

My thought was to maybe create some sort of list where the boundaries are defined, and then perhaps rerun the simulation with a different boundary each time and finally merging the images that appear.

The current code is quite long, but the parameters are all set in a main functions which looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    DirNameZmx = r'C:\Some\Path'
    FileNameZmx = r"Optics.zmx"

    DirNameResults = r"C:\Some\Other\Path"
    FileNameResults = r"Interferogram_Result"
    
    (QueueFieldsOut, QueueToDetector, ProcessRaytracing, ProcessesPsfWorkers, ProcessDetector) = \
        InitializeSimulation(DirNameZmx=DirNameZmx, FileNameZmx=FileNameZmx,
                             DirNameResults=DirNameResults, FileNameResults=FileNameResults,
                             FieldAngleHxMin=-0.02, FieldAngleHxMax=+0.02, dFieldAngleX=0.001,
                             FieldAngleHyMin=-0.06, FieldAngleHyMax=+0.06, dFieldAngleY=0.001,
                             NbrWavelength=1, Configurations=[1, 2], NbrRaysFieldRow=32, RAperture=0.99,
                             DetectorImageSize=11., DetectorPixelSize=0.011, ZeroPadding=8,
                             BatchRaysMax=512**2, NbrProcessWorkers=2)

    print(ProcessRaytracing.join())
    for Process in ProcessesPsfWorkers:
        print(Process.join())
        print(Process.name, Process.exitcode)

    print(ProcessDetector.join())

    data = np.load(os.path.join(DirNameResults, FileNameResults+'.npy'))
    plt.imshow(data, cmap="coolwarm")
    plt.show()
```

The FieldAngleHxMin/Max and FieldAngleHyMin/Max are the rectangle boundaries. The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently using to get the one rectangle, to give us a base with which to work and fit into your current approach?

Comment: of Course, my bad. I'll edit it in

Comment: Something else that I've thought of, where I'm unsure how exactly to do this, is that I could have a sort of reference file, in which I specify what the boundaries are for each smaller rectangle. I then import that file into my simulation script and then run the simulation with each set of boundaries, ie 9 times

Answer (score 0):

Simple iteration will do the work.

Try this:

```
def nine_squares(FieldAngleHxMin, FieldAngleHxMax, FieldAngleHyMin, FieldAngleHyMax):
    xstep = (FieldAngleHxMax - FieldAngleHxMin) / 3
    ystep = (FieldAngleHyMax - FieldAngleHyMin) / 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            xstartpoint = xstep + i * FieldAngleHxMin
            xendpoint = xstep + (i + 1) * FieldAngleHxMin
            ystartpoint = ystep + i * FieldAngleHyMin
            yendpoint = ystep + (i + 1) * FieldAngleHyMin
            yield (xstartpoint, xendpoint, ystartpoint, yendpoint)
```

It will return lists of start and end coordinates every time it is called.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't this get me 9 squares that fill the large square? Maybe I didn't clarify my problem properly: I'm trying to sort of sample the detector in 9 pre-defined "regions" rather than split the simulation time into 9ths.